# React JS - Replace matching string and add string to next matching string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Sorry
for the confusing / misleading title, wasn 't really sure how to word this one.

Basically, I am pulling players data from a CS:GO server, importantly the players rank which is given to me as a string such as `{default}[{pink}Master{default}]`

In-game colours inside of the curly braces get replaced with hex values, however for my react app I am trying to replace them so it'
s like`< span style = "color: #fff;" > [ < /span><span style="color: #ffb6c1;">Master</span > <span style="color: #fff;">]</span>`
    or[Master] where master would be some pink shade
    I can replace the {
        colours
    }
    with the opening span tag easily, however I 'm not sure how to get where the span should end.

Tried something like this

```js
const replaceColours = function(str) {
  const original = str;
  let index;
  let indexNext;
  let strOut;
  let colour;

  if (str.indexOf("{default}") !== -1) {
    index = str.indexOf("{default}");
    // console.log(index);
    strOut = str.substr(index);
    strOut = strOut.replace("{default}", "");
    // console.log(strOut);

    indexNext = strOut.indexOf("{");
    if (indexNext !== -1) {
        strOut = strOut.substr(0, indexNext);
    }

    // console.log(strOut);
    colour = reactStringReplace(str, "{default}", (match, i) => (
        <span key={i} style={{color: '#fff'}}></span>
    ));
  }

  console.log(colour);
  return colour;
}
```

reactStringReplace is from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-string-replace

My idea was to get the index of the first match {colour} then the index of the next { and get whatever is in-between those two.

Obviously doesn't work properly, but any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use React's [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) for this. It can be… well, dangerous, but it has it's uses.

For the actual replacement, `.replace()` should be sufficient, and hopefully easier than `.indexOf`:

```
str.replace(
  /{default}([^{$]*)/g,
  // '[^{$]*' means 'more than 0 characters except { or end-of-string'
  '<span style="color: #fff;">$1</span>'
  // $1 is a 'capture group' - everything between ( and ) in the regex above
)

/*
so…

{default}[{pink}Peter{default}]

…gets replaced to:

<span style="color: #fff;">[</span>{pink}Peter<span style="color: #fff;">]</span>
*/
```

Replacement of color strings (`{pink}` becomes `<span style='color: #ffb6c1'>`) would be similar.

Or, you can use just one replacement and look for colors in some sort of a config object, like in this snippet below:

```js
const colors = {
  default: "#fff",
  pink: "#f44283",
  blue: "#41d9f4",
  green: "#4cf441",
  yellow: "#f4d041"
};

const formatRank = rank =>
  rank
    .replace(
      // https://regex101.com/r/AbXrhg/1
      /{([^}]+)}([^{$]*)/g,
      // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter
      (match, color, content) =>
        `<span style='color: ${colors[color]};'>${content}</span>`
    );

const Player = ({ rank }) => (
  <div
    className="player"
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
      __html: formatRank(rank)
    }}
  />
);

const app = (
  <div>
    <Player rank="{default}[{pink}Peter{default}]" />
    <Player rank="{default}[{blue}Mary{default}] {green}kicks some asses" />
    <Player rank="{default}[{blue}John {pink}Paul {yellow}II.{default}]" />
    <Player rank="[{green}Fido{default}] {blue}i'm actually a {default}dog {yellow}" />
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(app, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```css
body {
  background: #444;
  font: 12pt/1.5em monospace;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.player {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.25em;
  margin: 0.5em 0.5em 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Whatever method you use, in an actual app, you need to **sanitize the strings to avoid XSS** vulnerabilities! Eg. strip any HTML tags before passing it to `formatRank` function to make sure that nobody can sneak a `<script>` in player's name.